# Magento 1.9.1 issue payment system dont work

Tags: paypal, payment, payment-methods

i use to have magento version 1.7 and afer recieving so many emails i decided to upgrade to Magento ver. 1.9.1.0. Now my customers can't pay and payment system does not work at all. It does all the step but when it get on onepage checkout then after clicking button "Place Order" it just stays there and do not redirect to paypal. Same with sage pay customers told its not working.

I install new version 1.9.1 from magento admin control panel.

does some one have similar issue. i am stuck from good few hours and cant find answer anywhere. Replaces id in one file still not working. can someone tell me real solution thanks.

Answer (score -1):

check it is the error from server side mbstring extension are enabled or not no codeing mistake mistake from server configuration so check it